# Why am I getting this memory access error 'double free or corruption'?

Tags: c, memory-access

I am getting the following type of error. I know it has something to do with me improperly accessing memory, but I don't exactly how. Please help me see where I have gone wrong.

*note I have simplified my function and it is not obvious what the variables are doing, I just need to know how I am implementing the function incorrectly or where I am misusing memory access.

```
int my_function(char const *file_name, size_t max)
        {

        myStruct.pStore = fopen(file_name,"w+");      //pStore is a FILE* 
        myStruct.max = max;                 

        // fill the with zeros ('0')
        int numberOfZeros = max*SIZE;
        char zeros[numberOfZeros];                      

        int i=0;
        while(i<numberOfZeros)         // insert zero's 
        {
                zeros[i]='0';
                i++;
        }
        fwrite(zeros,sizeof(char),numberOfZeros,myStruct.pStore);
        fclose(myStruct.pStore);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

The error I am given:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/.../: double free or corruption (top): 0x0804c008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73e42)[0xb7e82e42]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x154)[0xb7e72384]
/home/2012/spatar/cs/specs/release[0x80486b0]
/home/2012/spatar/cs/specs/release[0x8048acd]
/home/2012/spatar/cs/specs/release[0x8048af0]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb7e284d3]
/home/2012/spatar/cs/specs/release[0x80484e1]
 ======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 00:3b 2331829    /home/2012/spatar/cs/Aspecs/release
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 00:3b 2331829    /home/2012/spatar/cs/specs/release
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 00:3b 2331829    /home/2012/spatar/cs/specs/release
0804c000-0806d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7e0e000-b7e0f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7e0f000-b7fae000 r-xp 00000000 00:11 5415       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7fae000-b7fb0000 r--p 0019f000 00:11 5415       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7fb0000-b7fb1000 rw-p 001a1000 00:11 5415       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7fb1000-b7fb4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7fbc000-b7fd8000 r-xp 00000000 00:11 5426       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7fd8000-b7fd9000 r--p 0001b000 00:11 5426       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7fd9000-b7fda000 rw-p 0001c000 00:11 5426       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7fda000-b7fdd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7fdd000-b7fde000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7fde000-b7ffe000 r-xp 00000000 00:11 5405       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b7ffe000-b7fff000 r--p 0001f000 00:11 5405       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b7fff000-b8000000 rw-p 00020000 00:11 5405       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bffdf000-c0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Comment: Show the part of code where you free the memory.

Comment: Use a debugger. Use a debugger. Use a debugger.

Comment: The 'double free' led me to ask the same thing initially - but it looks like he's shown the entire function through the return statement.

Comment: I used gdb and it prints the same error. I am also using a makefile, how do I specify breaks when I am using multiple files?

Comment: Do you *use* `myStruct.pStore` elsewhere? Are you certain the problem is in this function?

Comment: yes. This is an assignment and this is the first function I work with...

Comment: Since this function neither allocates nor frees memory via `malloc()` and `free()`, it is very, very unlikely that this function is the direct cause of the trouble.  It isn't clear that it calls anything that is going to cause trouble, either.  I recommend trying [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: If you `fclose()` the same file again outside of `my_function()`, you may run into this problem.

Comment: How big is numberOfZeros? If it is large enough you could be overflowing the stack and corrupting memory. You really need to provide more example code (that compiles easily) and parameters to reproduce the problem. You will get better help this way.

Comment: I had a similar error trace from `/bin/bash` once (highly unlikely this was a bash bug). Turned out I had a bad memory module. If debugging does not help, rule out bad modules by using a memtest software like http://www.memtest86.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to free memory that has already been freed or was dereferenced.

Link your program with [efence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence) or run it with [valgrind](http://linux.die.net/man/1/valgrind).

This will tell you where your pointer gets dereferenced.

Comment: I am using gdb, are these ones better?

Comment: Just post the part where you free the memory and we can find the error in two minuts.

Answer (score 7):

Memory corruption is usually caused by writing beyond the end of allocated memory, and often it is by one byte because someone forgot to add one byte needed for the null to terminate a string.

Double free means free(x) was called twice in a row with the same value of x.  Somewhere in your code free(x) is called and then most likely in another piece of code free(x) is called again.

The easiest way to isolate the problem is to use gdb and observe what is happening as you step through your code.

In your my_function code above, there are no calls to malloc or free. The zeros buffer is on the stack and the while loop does not write beyond the end of buffer. The problem is in some other part of the code.  How long it would take to fix the problem(s) depends on how many places malloc/free/strdup etc. are called from.